# Parse .php and return as variable

Tags: php

So say I have a file page.php

```
<html>
Hello <?php echo $world;?>
</html>
```

I want to create a variable and assign it 'Hello world' using page.html

Something like

```
$world = 'world';
$mypage = parse_file('page.php');
```

I suppose I could wrap the entire file in doublequotes as such

```
$mypage="<html>
Hello $world
</html>";
```

but doublequote parsing is inefficient. Is there any easy of doing this without having to write a script that parses page.html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) will do this nicely

```
ob_start();
$world = 'world';
include('page.php');
$mypage = ob_get_clean();
```

Reference:

- [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)
- [`ob_get_clean()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: I considered that, but heredoc does have an overhead, especially if page.php is really large, no?

Comment: heredoc has less overhead than parsing a whole separate PHP file.